# How do I create the effect that when hovering the mouse over the image, a button appears. I've tried several ways, but I couldn't do it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm wanting to create the effect that when I hover the mouse over an image, an icon appears and when I remove the mouse the icon disappears, but I'm not succeeding.
I put an image as an example below, I wanted to recreate this effect in a shortcode

[image]

[image]

I tried to do it with Javascript using the mouseenter and mouseleave events, but whenever I hover over the icon it blinks.

```js
var produto = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-LoopProduct-link');
var icone = document.getElementsByClassName('shopengine-icon-add_to_favourite_1')


for (let i = 0; i < produto.length; i++) {
    produto[i].onmouseenter = function() {
        icone[i].style.display = "block";
    };

    produto[i].onmouseleave = function() {
       icone[i].style.display = "none";
    }; 

}
```

Comment: Show your effort ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I added the code I made in the post

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood from your question is that u want an icon when u hover over your product image.

Just Use Overlay concept.

[W3s Example for overlay on image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay_title.asp)

Use this doc,center your cart icon through styling.

Updating below codes.since iam unaware about links only answers.

```
<div class="product_container">
  <div class="product_detail">
       <img src="path/to/product_pic" alt="product image" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
       <img src="path/to/hover_cart_icon" alt="cart icon" 
         class="cart_icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Since i dont have full details,Classes for ur project iam assuming **product_container**  class with all product details and its hover icon.

**product_detail** div  class that contains product details,including imgs and details.
**cart_icon** is the class for hover icon.

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.product_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.product_detail {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product_container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to solve it with css.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).